# How is Backtracking done using recusrion in Binary Tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I'm trying to insert a Binary Node. My code is convoluted and there's no hope of rescuing it so I plan to rewrite it (basically I didn't account for backtracking and didn't think about the algorithm all that closely).

I'm trying to insert a Binary Node using in order traversal, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to backtrack.

```
     D
    / \
   B   E 
  / \ / \
 A  C F
```

How would I search through the left subtree of root D and then go back and search through the right one? It might be a stupid question, but I'm stumped. The best I can come up with is something like this:

```
 if (!root.hasLeftChild) {
      root = root.getLeftChild(); 
      recurse(root); 
 }
```

But when I reach the bottom, I can't go back up with the root. Also, it doesn't solve the problem where if I reach the bottom left node I have to fill up both children of that node before starting to backtrack.

I think I'm thinking about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tree :

```
     D
    / \
   B   E 
  / \ / \
 A  C F
```

For recurse :

Using InOrder Traverse

```
  if (root == null) 
    return;

      recurse(root.getLeftChild()); 
      int rootData = root.getData();
      recurse(root.getRightChild());
```

**Now, how it recurses :**

`root.getLeftChild()` will go on calling the left sub-child recursively unless it hits `null` node ( *so control wont go to `recurse(root.getRightChild());` unless `null` node is hit* )

Tree traveled so far :

```
         D
        / 
       B    
      / 
     A  
    /
  null <-- current Position
```

So once it reaches node `A`, `A.left == null`, so it recurses back to `node A` (assigning value of node to `rootData`)

```
     D
    / 
   B
  / 
 A  <-- current Position
```

and after this, it goes to next recursive call,  `recurse(root.getRightChild());`

```
         D
        / 
       B    
      / 
     A  
      \
      null <-- current Position
```

and now, since `left` and `right` of `A` have been traversed, control will go back to node `B` (which called `b.left = A`) and will look for `B.right`

---

**Take this Stack for example, for below tree** ( *node* , *value* )

```
     A
    / \
   B   E 
  / \ / \
 C  D F
```

[image]

**Steps :**

- `A` calls its left `B`, so A pushed in stack
- `B` calls its left `C`, so B pushed in stack
- `C` calls its left `null`, so C pushed in stack
- Now C has both `left` and `right` as `null`...so this marks the end of recursion for this node, hence its `pop`ped out of Stack
- Now, C is traversed completely, so, as B called C , control goes back to B and check which line called this command
- As `b.left` was executed, it will now go to `B.right` and `push` D...... *and this goes on* , this is called Recursion Stack

Comment: Okay, I'm a little bit confused about how it goes on to the next recursive call. 

When root == null, the method returns, so why does it keep going on?

Comment: i think u need to study about recursion stack...when a program is called recursively, each called sub program is operated into a fresh memory `stack`...once current stack operation is completed, the control goes back to the point which called the *just completed* Stack

Comment: Ahhhh, I never really had to use the recursion stack previously but my professor did try to explain it during lecture. I watched a YouTube video that explained it much more clearly. So basically, the stack looks like DBA, then it hits null and it pops A and resolves from int rootData = root.getData(); and recurses the getRightChild. Since there's nothing left to do, it goes back to B and does the same thing, then it goes back to A and it runs through it again on the right side, which then tries to get the leftChild again and runs through the method

Comment: Actually, one more thing. Why is A last? When D goes through the method, it has null for both children so shouldn't it be popped off as well? So it would look like: ABD -> AB -> A -> E -> EF -> E -> G?

Comment: Note how recursion happened for `B`, `B->C->null->C popped off -> back to B -> D -> null -> D popped off -> back to B -> B popped off`.....its happening because, once both the childs have been visited, then only parent is popped.... in trees, if u ever feel in doubt, just understand how the last parent and leaf is operated, then it'll help u understand better!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example. It visits all nodes in order by using recursion:

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        visitInOrder(new Node("D",
            new Node("B", new Node("A"), new Node("C")),
            new Node("F", new Node("E"))));
    }

    public static void visitInOrder(Node node) {
        if (node != null) {
            visitInOrder(node.left());
            System.out.println(node.name());
            visitInOrder(node.right());
        }
    }
}

class Node {

    private final String name;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;

    public Node(String name) {
        this(name, null);
    }

    public Node(String name, Node left) {
        this(name, left, null);
    }

    public Node(String name, Node left, Node right) {
        this.name = name;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public String name() { return name; }    

    public Node left() { return left; }

    public Node right() { return right; }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Comment: Your method `visitInOrder` is actually doing a pre-order visit, but your resulting output is the expected in-order result. Better fix the method.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose yes you are right. Now I fixed the order, but missed to fix the oputput. Will do it immediately. Thanks!

Comment: Ehhmmm: You misunderstood me! The output _was_ already correct. It _was_ in-order. Only the method was incorrect. Now you fixed the method, but also screw up the output completely. Now you have to change back your output to the initial form.

Comment: But [in-order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_.28symmetric.29) is: left, self, right. The output is ok, but completely confusing. The confirmed answer already catches the solution. I think my output is correct, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly: left, self, right! For a sub-tree with the parent node "B" and the left child node "A" and the right child node "C" (as in the question) the in-order output is "ABC". B as the current node - when visiting it - goes _in_ between A and C! Additionally, I did not have a look, whether your answer was a correct answer to the question. I only saw, that you posted an in-order output, but suggested a pre-order method. Currently you have an in-order method and an output that is neither in- nor pre- nor post-order. It's messed up. The in-order output of the example will be the sorted output.

Comment: My example tree is not in sync with the tree in the question. That's why my output differs. But thanks for the many comments. I messed up this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to do a depth first search - which you can find in any number of books or on wikipedia.

They key, essentially, is that your function recursively calls itself on each child. e.g:

```
public Node findSpot(Node node, List<Node> visits){
    visits.add(node);
    //condition check, return this node if its the right node.
    Node result = null;
    for(Node child : node.getListChildren()){
        if((result findSpot(child)) != null){
             return result
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So this recursively checks down the nodes, putting a new method on the stack for each layer of depth in the tree. It then checks the next branch if it doesnt find what its looking for. The list of visits will let you see in what order it visits the nodes, so you can look. THis will help you understand how it works.