# Path from given node to root in a binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-tree

I've been trying to figure this problem out for a while now and I'm not really getting anywhere with it. Essentially, given some binary tree and a node on that tree, how would you find the path from that given node back to the root?

Does anyone have an idea on how I could implement this? Any input would be greatly appreciated, my sincere thanks from a novice coder.

Comment: give your code. how u store data

Comment: Does your node implementation have a notion of parent, or does it only know its children?

Comment: Hint: Stack, DFS

Comment: you can do it recursively

Comment: which data is stored? is it a sorted binary tree?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is Backtracking done using recusrion in Binary Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23059127/how-is-backtracking-done-using-recusrion-in-binary-tree)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments, my apologies for asking a question which has been previously answered! You guys have been a great help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find the path from one node to another, you have to recursively traverse the tree from the origin node down to its children, their children, and so on until you get to the destination node. Once you get to the destination node, you need to backtrack the path of nodes that took you to that destination node back to the root. One way to do this is a modified version of *pre-order traversal*  in which one first checks the root, then its left subtree, and then its right subtree.

```
public boolean getPath(root, value){
    if(root == null){
        return false;
    }
    if(root.value === value){
        System.out.println(root.value);
        return true;
    }
    int onPath = getPath(root.left, value);
    if(onPath){
        System.out.println(root.value);
        return true;
    }
    onPath = getPath(root.right,value);
    if(onPath){
        System.out.println(root.value);
        return true;
    }
    return false; //a path was never found
}
```

In the method above, we compare the value of `root` with the destination `value`. If they are not equal we check the left subtree. If the destination is not in the left subtree we then check the right subtree. If the destination still is not found, `false` is returned so that when going back up the recursion call stack, we can let the node's parent know that there is no path to the destination from that node. If however, the destination is found, then we return `true` so that when going back up the recursion call stack we can tell the node's parent and its parent and so on that a path has been found.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris! Really appreciate you taking the time to explain this.

Comment: @JimBouquet  glad i could help. Good luck coding!